Spring Flux Sink Reactor - best way to monitor
My question - I have a flux endpoint: (spring boot webflux, flux)
@GetMapping(produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE, value = "/myendpoint")
public Flux<ServerSentEvent<ObjectNode>> subscribeToMyEndpoint

which is backed by Sinks.
Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer(100)

In general I want to monitor the data on this endpoint. Is the buffer used? How much data is sent? How many connections are there?
I have spring actuator and prometheus installed. Thus I can create a guage to log data. I assume that almost everything that I do, others have done before. Is there any type of best practices for this? Any advice?
I am only counting how many message are sent and how many queues I have. I have not tried to log buffers.

I assumed that this is not done often. Replying to my own question. I do have an issue - with the clients. The clients receive errors and try to reconnect. Since the connection is open they can not. (I know that is the problem of the client.) To monitor, for every sind and every minute I add to a micrometer guague sink.currentSubscriberCount() . Then I can monitor in Prometheus the subcriber count.

BUT, since my issue is really with the front end developer, I also now monitor (in a map) the amount of connection attempts per minute by location. If the location starts spamming me for new connections, then I know that the other side has lost his reference to his OPEN connection. I have to fix that for him, by killing the sink. Killing the sink means that he can reconnect because his OPEN connection is then closed. I will now do my developer thing and moan about life being incorrect.
